# Ionicons return 404 in Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionicons

I updated npm today, and noticed many Ionic icons from [ionicons.com](https://ionicons.com/) return 404 error. I've found [a workaround](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/updated-from-4-rc-to-v4-ionicon-not-showing-resolved/154237/2) (basically, modifying the angular.json file). I'm not very comfortable with this, as I fear running into the same problem (and others) every time I update, considering this file must have been automatically modified by the updates I did. How do I fix this?

[image]

**Ionic Info**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (%USER_HOME%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.0
   @capacitor/core : 1.5.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.14.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.6
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually what happened was I was using v5 icons in v4. The problem wasn't the `npm update` which I did. So I just decided to upgrade to v5.

```
npm update -g cordova ionic
npm install @ionic/angular@5.0.0-rc.3
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save dev
```

**Also**, I'll like to point out, the usual [Ionicicons.com](https://ionicons.com) link now contains only v5 icons. There's a new  [Ionicons v4 link](https://ionicons.com/v4/). Icons from there work on v3 and v4.

Answer (score 2):

Ionicons 5.0.0 is out. Check the CHANGELOG to convert your icons to the new syntax or new available names.

For example if you want to use `md` or `ios` versions, this will be the new approach:

```html
<ion-icon ios="heart-outline" md="heart-sharp"></ion-icon>
```

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks. Your answer pointed me to my real problem; I was using those v5 icons on my Ionic4 project.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my 404 errors by updating my Angular.json like this.

```js
assets: [
  ...
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
    "output": "./svg"
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case (`"@ionic/angular": "^6.0.11"`) the input path is: `"node_modules/@ionic/core/node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg"`.